# How to change color of title area on android

Tags: android, css, codenameone

I created a Codename One project with the flatBlue theme, which has a light blue title area, and then changed the TitleArea to green. I changed both the background color (in the color tab) and the 9 TitleArea.* Multi-Images (3 images in each Multi-image) to the desired color. In the simulator, using the nexus5 skin, everything looks fine, but on an actual Android Phone, there is still a thin light blue line between the grey status bar and the green title area. How do I fix this?

Kind regards, Frans

Comment: please clear your question .. its too hard to understand and attach image if possible @Frans

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: can you add some image or image links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I made a screenshot of my phone to post it with the question above, I noticed the blue line was not there in the screenshot. So apparently, it was a visual effect of the phone screen caused by the adjacent grey of the status bar and the green of the title area. I fixed it by making the status bar a darker shade of green (instead of the original grey), which eliminated the unwanted visual effect.

Comment: Check out this section https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html search for colors.xml for instructions on how to color the status bar area

Comment: Hello Shai, Adding a colors.xml file is exactly what I did to fix the issue. Thanks, Frans.